# Typing 'python' in my terminal is met with `zsh: permission denied: python`

Tags: python, zsh

When I type `python` into a terminal, it responds with

> zsh: permission denied: python

It seems like python3 is the main installed python version - that's what is installed into `usr/bin`. Every tutorial I see says to type `python` and it shows you the version of python3 that is installed. So, why would this command not work? Do I need to set the alias of `python` to point to python3?

Here is the output of some commands in my terminal, for clarity:

```
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % python -V
zsh: permission denied: python
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % python2 -V
zsh: command not found: python2
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % python3 -V
Python 3.9.6
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.18 (set by /Users/stephen/.pyenv/version)
  3.9.10
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % python
zsh: permission denied: python
stephen@Stephens-MBP 3rd % type python
python not found
```

Comment: What does `type python` say?

Comment: @Barmar

`type python` says `python not found`

Comment: Do you have a file named `python` in your directory?

Comment: in usr/bin there is only a file named `python3`. Which I'm confused about - shouldn't there be a file named `python`?

Comment: I didn't ask about `/usr/bin`. I asked if there's a file with that name in your current directory.

Comment: E.g. `ls -l python`

Comment: no, there is no file named python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255042/discussion-between-fewaf-and-barmar).

Comment: I would care first about the _python not found_ than on the permission problem.  First of all, which Python would you like to be executed when just typing `python`? Can you run this Python of your longing by specifying the explicit path name?

Comment: Well mainly I want it to point to whatever I set with pyenv. In the tutorial it says if you use pyenv to set the version, then when you type python, it'll show that version:
```pyenv global 3.10.2

python --version
# Python 3.10.2```

 I'm not sure why that isn't happening for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the "pyenv versions" command, proceed with the following steps:

1. pyenv global 3.9.10
2. You need to set up the PATH for pyenv in zsh, so add the following lines to your .zshrc file:

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

3. source .zshrc
4. python3 --version